# R studio, shiny package. How to generate plots which depend on user choice from selectInput

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have csv file with some attributes such as age or potencial of selected football players. I would like to make a couple of different plots, which depend on  users choice. For example if user choose from the first selectInput option "sprint speed" and "potencial" from second selectInput, the server function will generate plots with "sprint speed" as x value and "potencial" as y value. Here is my code (which generates a lot of errors):

```
**variables**
data <- read.csv("H:\\med\\lab45\\players205.csv", header = T, sep=",")

choices <- c("overall","age","potencial","preffered foot", "free kick accuracy",
         "heading accuracy", "height", "weight", "sprint speed")
tempData <- cbind(data[2],data[45],data[3],data[4],data[14],
              data[9],data[42],data[43],data[18])
names(tempData) <- c("overall","age","potencial","preffered foot", 
  "free kick accuracy","heading accuracy", "height", "weight", "sprint speed")

**UI**
ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput(inputId = "selectX", label = "select x value", choices = choices, selectize = FALSE),
  selectInput(inputId = "selectY", label = "select y value", choices = choices, selectize = FALSE),
  actionButton(label = "set new values", inputId = "submitValues"),
  plotOutput("myFirstPlot")
)

**server**
server <- function(input, output) {

  x <- reactiveValues(data = "age")

  y <- reactiveValues(data = "potencial")

  observeEvent(input$selectX,{x$data = input$selectX})
  observeEvent(input$selectY,{y$data = input$selectY})

  output$myFirstPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(x ~ y, data=tempData)
  })
}

shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

and here is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you update this to include a sample of your data please? You can use `dput(head(data))` in R to get an output others can use to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more about this.

Comment: In your plot try `plot(x$data ~ y$data, data=tempData)`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Qe8eYvr - here is a sample data

Comment: @JohnPaul it didn't work for me

Comment: _it_ `didn't work for me` you _might_ need to give more detail to get help.